# Where should methods be placed; ids vs NumericProperty; kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I have a very basic kivy code. I have the .py file and the .kv file. The questions are: where should the methods be placed? In this example the 2 methods that interact are 'def GetTicker(ticker):' and 'def GetTickers(self):'. I have placed both outside of any class, because I could not get the code to work otherwise; however I think the proper way to code would be to place them inside the 'app' class.
As an aside I am very confused about where/when the 'self' should be passed. I'm working by trial and error here.
Then there is the 'NumericProperty'. I read here that when it is updated, it automatically updates the widgets that are associated with it. It doesn't for me, therefore I had to create Id's for some labels; but the id's won't work at the beginning of the run, only on update.

I'm using python 3.9 and kivy 2.0.0, PyCharm 2021.3.1 (Community Edition) on win10 box.

Any and all assistance will be greatly appreciated.
Ray

the .py file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.size = (300, 300)

import time
from yahoo_fin.stock_info import get_live_price   # This API only gets the live price
from yahoo_fin import stock_info as si            # This is SLOWER than the above API, buts gets more info


class MyBoxLayout(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def press(self):
        name = self.ids.ticker_name.text.upper()
        self.ids.ticker_value.text = self.GetTicker(name)

    def update(self):
        #GetTickers(self)  # This won't work here :(
        self.ids.mydow_price.text, self.ids.mydow_chg = self.GetTicker("^DJI")
        self.ids.mysp_price.text, self.ids.mysp_chg = self.GetTicker("^GSPC")
        self.ids.mynasdaq_price.text, self.ids.mynasdaq_chg.text = self.GetTicker("^IXIC")
        self.ids.myeuro_price, self.ids.myeuro_chg.text = self.GetTicker("EURUSD=X")
        #print(self.ids.amazon_id.text)


class MyOtherBoxlayout(BoxLayout):
    pass

class MyTicker(TextInput):
    pass

class gridlayout(GridLayout):
    pass

def GetTicker(ticker):
    # data = get_live_price(ticker)
    data = si.get_quote_table(ticker)
    price = data['Quote Price']
    change = price - data['Previous Close']
    # print("Price: %.3f" % price)
    # print("Change: %.3f" % change)
    return [str("%s" % format(price, ',.3f')), str("%s" % format(change, ',.3f'))]

def GetTickers(self):
    self.dow_price, self.dow_chg = self.GetTicker("^DJI")
    self.sp_price, self.sp_chg = self.GetTicker("^GSPC")
    self.nasdaq_price, self.nasdaq_chg = self.GetTicker("^IXIC")
    self.euro_price, self.euro_chg = self.GetTicker("EURUSD=X")

# This is the app class
class StockTickerApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        App.title = "Ray's Stock Ticker"

        dow_price = NumericProperty(0.00)
        dow_chg = NumericProperty(0.00)
        sp_price = NumericProperty(0.00)
        sp_chg = NumericProperty(0.00)
        nasdaq_price = NumericProperty(0.00)
        nasdaq_chg = NumericProperty(0.00)
        euro_price = NumericProperty(0.00)
        euro_chg = NumericProperty(0.00)

        start_time = time.time()
        self.GetTickers()
        end_time = time.time()
        print (end_time - start_time)




# and its run here
StockTickerApp().run()
```

the .kv file

```
MyBoxLayout:

<MYLabel@ButtonBehavior+Label>: # this is something I found that helps make a label behave
                                # like a button.

<MyBoxLayout>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (153/255, 255/255, 255/255, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    padding: ("15dp", "15dp", "15dp", "15dp") #left, top, right, bottom
    spacing: "10dp"
    orientation: "vertical"
    #
    # 1st widget
    #
    Label:
        text: "Stocks Ticker"
        size_hint: 1, .1
        #pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        color:0,0,0,1
    #
    # 2nd widget
    #
    BoxLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: (19/255,202/255,55/255,1) # lime more intense
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        padding: ("10dp", "0dp", "15dp", "0dp")
        spacing: "20dp"
        orientation: "horizontal"
        size_hint: 1, .4
        #pos_hint: {"center": .5}
        Label:
            text: " Enter Stock"
            size_hint: .6, .5
            pos_hint: {"center_X":.5, "top": .7}
            color: 72/255,89/255,89/255,1
        MyTicker: # this is a textinput widget
            id: ticker_name
            text: ""
            size_hint: .6, .6
            pos_hint: {"top": .8}
        Label:
            id: ticker_value
            #text: " Enter Stock"
            size_hint: .5, .1
            color: 0,0,0,1
            pos_hint: {"top":.5, "center": 1}
    #
    # 3rd widget
    #
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: 1, .3

        Button:
            #id: "Find_Value"
            text: "Find Value"
            on_press: root.press()
    #
    # 4th widget
    #
    gridlayout:
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: (19/255,202/255,55/255,1) # lime more intense
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
        rows: 4
        cols: 3
        padding: "10dp"
        MYLabel:
            color: 72/255,89/255,89/255,1
            text: "Dow"
            text_size: self.size
            halign: 'left'
            on_press: root.update()
        MYLabel:
            id: mydow_price
            color: 0,0,0,1
            text: app.dow_price
            text_size: self.size
            halign: 'right'
            on_press: root.update()
        MYLabel:
            id: mydow_chg
            color: 0,0,0,1
            text: app.dow_chg
            text_size: self.size
            halign: 'right'
            on_press: root.update()

        MYLabel:
            text: "S&P 500"
            color: 72/255,89/255,89/255,1
            text_size: self.size
            halign: 'left'
            on_press: root.update()
        MYLabel:
            id: mysp_price
            text: app.sp_price
            color: 0,0,0,1
            text_size: self.size
            halign: 'right'
        MYLabel:
            id: mysp_chg
            text: app.sp_chg
            color: 0,0,0,1
            text_size: self.size
            halign: 'right'

        MYLabel:
            text: "Nasdaq"
            color: 72/255,89/255,89/255,1
            text_size: self.size
            halign: 'left'
            on_press: root.update()
        MYLabel:
            id: mynasdaq_price
            text: app.nasdaq_price
            color: 0,0,0,1
            text_size: self.size
            halign: 'right'
        MYLabel:
            id: mynasdaq_chg
            text: app.nasdaq_chg
            color: 0,0,0,1
            text_size: self.size
            halign: 'right'

        MYLabel:
            text: "Euro/USD"
            color: 72/255,89/255,89/255,1
            text_size: self.size
            halign: 'left'
            on_press: root.GetTickers()
        MYLabel:
            id: myeuro_price
            text: app.euro_price
            color: 0,0,0,1
            text_size: self.size
            halign: 'right'
        MYLabel:
            id: myeuro_chg
            text: app.euro_chg
            color: 0,0,0,1
            text_size: self.size
            halign: 'right'
```

Comment: Kivy properties (like `NumericProperty`) are supposed to be defined at class level.

Comment: Yes, that is clear but my understanding is that if they are associated to a widget, the widget would be updated each time the NP changes. So I'm questioning my code.

Comment: *'the widget would be updated each time the NP changes...'* for this to happen you need to bind the associated property to a callback function. More information [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html#observe-property-changes).

Comment: I'm no t sure how to do that other than what I've already done. In the .kv file the labels (some) have the text value bound to a NP:  "dow_price = NumericProperty(0.00)" 'text: app.dow_price'. Is there any other way of doing it?